# Making certain parts invisible when hovering over it

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to make a little game. For the game I have made a grid full of *rect* which fill the entire screen, when I hover over some *rect* they have to disappear. Is there a way to code this?

this is what I have:

```
  float opac = 1000;
  float X;
  float Y;
  void setup(){
  size(600,600);

  }

  void draw(){
  background(220,250,20);


  int countX=0;
  int countY=0;

  //filling the screen
  for(countY = -20 ; countY<height+20 ; countY=countY+20){
    for( countX = -20 ; countX<width+20 ; countX=countX+20){

    dot(countX,countY);
    }
  }



  fill(20,200,10);
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,20,20);

  }

  void dot(float x, float y){
  noStroke();
  fill(255,22,22,opac);
  rect(x,y,20,20);
  }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not sure that there's any way to truly hide it. You could redraw the rectangle filled with the background color, then of course change it back when the mouse leaves the rectangle

Answer (score 0):

Just use if statements to check whether `mouseX` and `mouseY` are inside your square. If so, don't draw it. Something like this:

```
for(countY = -20 ; countY<height+20 ; countY=countY+20){
    for( countX = -20 ; countX<width+20 ; countX=countX+20){
        if(mouseX > x && mouseX < x+20 && mouseY > y && mouseY < y+20){
            //mouse is inside square
        } 
        else{
            dot(countX,countY);
        }
    }
}
```